# Building coreboot: undefined reference __udivmoddi4

Tags: gcc

In building coreboot I got error regarding during linking:
 `coreboot/src/console/vtxprintf.c:102: undefined reference to '__udivmoddi4'`.

Where can I find the library containing this function?

I'm building coreboot for x86_64 (Lenovo x230) using gcc (8.1.1 20180531).

Coreboot - git hash: f59a052ee8dae6f1378514cb622d229e652ad2f6

Comment: I don't think it should ever be generated on x86_64 (is it building for 32 bits?), but the related functions are in libgcc.a / libgcc_s.so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__udivmoddi4` is a function in libgcc which is used to implement a combined unsigned division/modulo operation for what GCC calls DI mode (doubled-up integers, 64-bit on i686).  It is used for operations like this one:

```
unsigned long long
div (unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long *p)
{
  *p = a % b;
  return a / b;
}
```

The use of `__udivmoddi4` on i386 is a new optimization in GCC 7, [related to this patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-10/msg02483.html).  Previous versions emitted separate calls to `__umoddi3` and `__udivdi3`, basically doing the same work twice.

Normally, all these functions are provided by `libgcc`, but Coreboot does not link against the standard libraries.  It supplies its own implementations of these functions in `payloads/libpayload/libc/64bit_div.c`, but `__udivmoddi4` has yet to be added there.

Either you implement the function yourself (easiest way would be to call `__umoddi3` and `__udivdi3` from it), or you use GCC 6 to compile Coreboot for the time being.  Lowering the optimization level just for the `printf` implementation might constitute a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know coreboot builds its own GCC. I'll try the latter as I don't want to use GCC 6.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today, and found out that Coreboot is made to be built using the i386 toolchain, not the x86_64. See https://doc.coreboot.org/tutorial/part1.html:

> Note that the i386 toolchain is currently used for all x86 platforms, including x86_64.

After cloning coreboot, one should run `make crossgcc-i386 CPUS=$(nproc)` to build a compatible toolchain.

Here is the mailing list that gave me the hint:
https://mail.coreboot.org/pipermail/coreboot/2018-August/087195.html